# VS Code compare changes, how to accept/reject

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Today I discovered that VS Code automatically recognizes when I open a file that has merge conflicts. In the beginning, I see several commands available, including "compare changes". I like this display far better than the other, I would like to work from it. It shows the changes at a much finer granularity. But now, I can't see buttons to accept or reject changes. Are they hiding in plain sight somewhere on this screen? Where to go from here?

Part of the issue is, I would like to edit through the conflict on a line-by-line basis, not accepting or rejecting the whole change as it was presented to me. Can this view help me with that?

[image: A single line I would like to accept]